Swipe right to navigate back in compose
In my Android app, I am displaying data in the lazy column, when the user clicks on one of the items in the list, it navigates to a new screen ("B") and when the user presses back it navigates back. till here it works great.
I have implemented a swipe-back feature where the user swipes on screen from left to right on screen B, screen moves to the right once the user has swiped the screen more than half of the device screen, the screen gets closed and navigates back.
The problem is for a second, the user sees a blank screen when they navigate back by swiping, and then the main screen.
How main screen be visible below, when the user swipes right?
I want to achieve this behaviour:

What My code does is this:

Code:
 @Composable
fun App() {

    val navController = rememberNavController()

    MainScreen(
        navController = navController,
    ) { innerPadding ->
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = NavScreen.Home.route,
            enterTransition = { fadeIn() },
            exitTransition = { fadeOut() }
        ) {
            composable(NavScreen.Home.route) {
                MainScreen(innerPadding = innerPadding, navController = navController)
            }
            composable(
                route = NavScreen.Preview.route,
                enterTransition = {
                    slideIntoContainer(
                        AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                        animationSpec = tween(300)
                    )
                },
                exitTransition = {
                    slideOutOfContainer(
                        AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left,
                        animationSpec = tween(50)
                    )
                },
                popEnterTransition = {
                    fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(50))
                },
                popExitTransition = {
                    slideOutOfContainer(
                        AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                        animationSpec = tween(300)
                    )
                }
            ) {
                PreviewScreen(
                    innerPadding = innerPadding,
                    navController = navController
                )
            }
}
}
}

MainScreen:
    @Composable
fun MainScreen(
    innerPadding: PaddingValues,
    navController: NavController,
) {
        LazyColumn(
            state = rememberLazyListState(),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.White)
                .padding(top = innerPadding.calculateTopPadding())
        )
        {
            items(120) {
                Card(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(50.dp)
                        .padding(top = 5.dp, start = 2.dp, end = 2.dp)
                        .clickable {
                            navController.navigate(NavScreen.Preview.route)
                        },
                    elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(15.dp),
                    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(Color.White)
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Hello $it")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

preview screen:
 @Composable
fun PreviewScreen(
    innerPadding: PaddingValues,
    navController: NavController,
) {
    val offsetX = remember { Animatable(0f) }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    var componentWidth by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    var isDragging by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .zIndex(1f)  // Keep this above the main screen during swipe
            .padding(innerPadding)
            .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.value.roundToInt(), 0) }
            .pointerInput(Unit) {
                detectHorizontalDragGestures(
                    onDragStart = { offset ->
                        isDragging = offset.x <= componentWidth * 0.15f
                    },
                    onDragEnd = {
                        if (isDragging) {
                            coroutineScope.launch {
                                if (offsetX.value > componentWidth / 2f) {
                                   
                                    navController.popBackStack()
                                } else {
                                    offsetX.animateTo(
                                        0f,
                                        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 300)
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        isDragging = false
                    },
                    onDragCancel = {
                        isDragging = false
                    }
                ) { change, dragAmount ->
                    if (isDragging) {
                        change.consume()
                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            offsetX.snapTo(
                                (offsetX.value + dragAmount).coerceIn(
                                    0f,
                                    componentWidth.toFloat()
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .layout { measurable, constraints ->
                val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
                componentWidth = placeable.width
                layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {
                    placeable.place(0, 0)
                }
            }
    ) {
        Column(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Green)
                .padding(horizontal = 5.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text(text = "Hello", fontSize = 20.sp)
        }
    }
}


Unfortunately, it seems that what you are trying to achieve is not possible using the original NavHost. As soon as a navController.navigate() happens and the enterTransition / exitTransition are performed, the previous Composable is removed, it is no longer behind the current one. So if you move your new Composable using the offset Modifier, there will nothing be visible behind it.
However, I would also argue that with the now default Android Gesture Navigation, the swiping animation might not be ideal anyway, as a swipe from the very edge will trigger the system back behavior.
So you would have to implement a custom navigation using a root Box Composable and stack everything on top of each other, but this will probably cause a number of further complexities.
So, what you can achieve with out of the box tools is like this:

Code:
@Composable
fun NavigationAnimation() {

    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = "ScreenA",
    ) {
        composable(
            route = "ScreenA",
            enterTransition = {
                fadeIn(initialAlpha = 0.2f, animationSpec = tween(2000)) +
                        slideInHorizontally(
                            animationSpec = tween(1500),
                            initialOffsetX = { fullWidth -> -fullWidth / 2 }
                        )
            },
            exitTransition = {
                fadeOut(targetAlpha = 0.2f, animationSpec = tween(2000)) +
                        slideOutHorizontally(
                            animationSpec = tween(1500),
                            targetOffsetX = { fullWidth -> -fullWidth / 2 }
                        )
            }
        ) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Yellow)
            ) {
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                    onClick = { navController.navigate("ScreenB") }
                ) {
                    Text(text = "SCREEN B")
                }
            }
        }
        composable(
            route = "ScreenB",
            enterTransition = {
                slideInHorizontally(
                    animationSpec = tween(1500),
                    initialOffsetX = { fullWidth -> fullWidth }
                )
            },
            exitTransition = {
                slideOutHorizontally(
                    animationSpec = tween(1500),
                    targetOffsetX = { fullWidth -> fullWidth }
                )
            }
        ) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Green)
            ) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                    text = "SCREEN B"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

Also be aware that Google themselves are working on predictive back gestures, which sort of will depict a similar behavior as you are trying to implement now.

I don't think it's possible to achieve this with separate navigations because when transition ends a Composable is removed from composition graph. As you can see in your image MainScreen enters composition after NavController calls navigate.
One of the ways, and easiest but not stable for every ui composition, to achieve this is getting Bitmap of MainScreen and drawing it behind root or PreviewScreen. But there might occur flashes or screen position not be 100% accurate.
Other option is putting MainScreen and PreviewScreen in same navigation and changing offset of each other while PreviewScreen is clicked. Also as i can see from original gif they keep TopAppbar shared while changing offset of either screen on drag.
val width = constraints.maxWidth.toFloat()

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .graphicsLayer {
            translationX = -offsetX.value
        }
) {
    MainScreen {
        coroutineScope.launch {
            data = Holder(it)
            isDetailScreen = true
            offsetX.animateTo(
                targetValue = width,
                animationSpec = tween(300)
            )
        }
    }
}

data?.let {
    if (isDetailScreen) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .zIndex(100f)
                .graphicsLayer {
                    translationX = size.width - offsetX.value
                }
        ) {
            PreviewScreen(it.value)
        }
    }
}
}

Since, PreviewScreen might need to enter composition, often detail screens require data from previous screen
after MainScreen is clicked you can hold a nullable data that you can pass from main to preview and add PreviewScreen to composition afterwards.

In LaunchedEffect check if we moved from detail screen so scroll doesn't happen in MainScreen
data class Holder(val value: Int)
@Composable
fun App() {

    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(
        modifier = Modifier.systemBarsPadding().fillMaxSize(),
        navController = navController,
        enterTransition = { EnterTransition.None },
        exitTransition = { ExitTransition.None },
        startDestination = "Main"
    ) {

     
        composable(
            route = "Main",
            enterTransition = {
                slideIntoContainer(
                    AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                    animationSpec = tween(300)
                )
            },
            exitTransition = {
                slideOutOfContainer(
                    AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Left,
                    animationSpec = tween(50)
                )
            },
            popEnterTransition = {
                fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(50))
            },
            popExitTransition = {
                slideOutOfContainer(
                    AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Right,
                    animationSpec = tween(300)
                )
            }
        ) {

            val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
            val offsetX = remember {
                Animatable(0f)
            }

            var isDetailScreen by remember {
                mutableStateOf(false)
            }

            var data by remember {
                mutableStateOf<Holder?>(null)
            }

            LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                snapshotFlow {
                    offsetX.value
                }.map { it != 0f }
                    .collectLatest {
                        isDetailScreen = it
                    }
            }

            BackHandler(isDetailScreen) {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    offsetX.animateTo(
                        0f,
                        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 300)
                    )
                }
            }

            Column {

                TopAppBar(
                    navigationIcon = {
                        IconButton(
                            onClick = {
                                if (isDetailScreen) {
                                    coroutineScope.launch {
                                        offsetX.animateTo(
                                            0f,
                                            animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 300)
                                        )
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ) {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.AutoMirrored.Default.ArrowBack,
                                contentDescription = null
                            )
                        }
                    },
                    title = {
                        Text(if (isDetailScreen) "Preview" else "Main")
                    }
                )

                val dragModifier = Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
                    val componentWidth = size.width
                    detectHorizontalDragGestures(
                        onDragEnd = {
                            coroutineScope.launch {
                                if (offsetX.value > componentWidth / 2f) {
                                    offsetX.animateTo(
                                        componentWidth.toFloat(),
                                        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 300)
                                    )
                                } else {
                                    offsetX.animateTo(
                                        0f,
                                        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 300)

                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ) { _, dragAmount ->
                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            offsetX.snapTo(
                                (offsetX.value - dragAmount).coerceIn(
                                    0f,
                                    componentWidth.toFloat()
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
                BoxWithConstraints(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                ) {
                    val width = constraints.maxWidth.toFloat()

                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .graphicsLayer {
                                translationX = -offsetX.value
                            }
                    ) {
                        MainScreen {
                            coroutineScope.launch {
                                data = Holder(it)
                                isDetailScreen = true
                                offsetX.animateTo(
                                    targetValue = width,
                                    animationSpec = tween(300)
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    data?.let {
                        if (isDetailScreen) {
                            Box(
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .zIndex(100f)
                                    .then(dragModifier)
                                    .graphicsLayer {
                                        translationX = size.width - offsetX.value
                                    }
                            ) {
                                PreviewScreen(it.value)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

